# How to use Bash in adb (android ) instead of Shell?

Tags: android, bash, adb, sh

I'm currently using adb terminal to access my database files. However, I can only access the terminal using this:

```
./adb shell
```

I would like to switch from sh to bash as it is much more convenient for some shortcuts. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you have `bash` binary on your `Android` device?

Answer (score 1):

i dont think adb have bash options , if you type **adb help** , you will see options for shell and not for bash

```
shell:
 shell [-e ESCAPE] [-n] [-Tt] [-x] [COMMAND...]
     run remote shell command (interactive shell if no command given)
     -e: choose escape character, or "none"; default '~'
     -n: don't read from stdin
     -T: disable PTY allocation
     -t: force PTY allocation
     -x: disable remote exit codes and stdout/stderr separation
 emu COMMAND              run emulator console command
```

May be if you can share, what specific difficulties you are facing in running the shortcut or command

However if you still wanted to use adb with bash , you can have a look on below link

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19315/how-to-set-bash-as-default-shell

Answer (score 0):

Answered [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/232537/20417)

Found the proper & simple way from a Linux box:

```
adb shell -t bash -i
```

You logon directly via [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) in interactive way.

To not having to remember this command all the times, I personally
use an alias, simply add this to your `~/.bashrc` on Linux box:

```
alias adb_shell='adb shell -t bash -i'
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then all is configured, simply run

```
adb_shell
```

and enjoy all `bash` features like tab completion and anything. \o/