# Bash array outputs numbers instead of strings

Tags: android, bash, adb

I'm trying to split a line with multiple ' in it, but the result are numbers, not strings, trying to get the 1st occurrence of ', I mean the string YouTube down there:

```sh
line="application: label='YouTube' icon='res/uFR.xml'"
echo $line
IFS="'"
read -a stringArray <<< "$line"
echo "${stringArray[1]}"
```

Current Output:

`112`

Expected Output:

`YouTube`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYcIh.jpg

Comment: Hi, please read [mcve] and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I can't tell if it's the problem here, but setting `IFS` globally like this can cause all sorts of weird problems, especially when you're also using word splitting (which depends on `IFS`) to get the items the `for` loop iterates over (which also isn't very safe on its own, either). It's better to make it a prefix of the `read` command (`IFS=\' read -a ...`) so that it only applies to that one command.

Comment: @Nic3500 How's now?

Comment: the latest edit (`line=.. / echo $line / IFS=... / read -a ... / echo ...`) works for me and generates as output the string `YouTube`; and the array contents look correct: `typeset -p stringArray` => `declare -a stringArray=([0]="application: label=" [1]="YouTube" [2]=" icon=" [3]="res/uFR.xml")`

Comment: please update the question what a textual snippet of the code that shows up in the imgur image, making sure to specify that you're running this script under `adb`

Comment: ahhh, the question was mis-tagged; I've added `adb` to the tags; my confirmation was based on running through `bash`; I don't work with `adb` but a bit of googling shows (me) that `adb` doesn't normally run under `bash`; this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65546964) has a suggestion for invoking `bash` from within `adb` ... perhaps that may help? and with that I've exhausted my `adb` 'expertise' ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you believe this guys ?! It should be capital A, not small a, must be Bash magic :)

```sh
read -A stringArray <<< "$line"
```

Comment: I'd like to note here that Linux files must've combatible line ending to be read correctly: Notepad++ -> Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Unix (LF), or you can just Console.Write("string" + "\n");

Answer (score -1):

i think the `IFS` variable should use quotes for it to be literal, if this does not work then to also escape the quote character with `IFS='\''`

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the case, it works fine in Ubuntu like the screenshot in the main post says.